# number of possibilities to interview candidates

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

Given 8 candidates for a job, Calculate the possibilities to interview them in one day if each one is interviewed at least once and no more than 3 times.

**Note**: the total number of interviews is 13 and that order matters.

Here is my suggested answer which I was told is wrong:

[image]

could someone help me find the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At most 2 candidates are interviwed 3 times.

- Exactly 2 are. Then exactly one is twice and other once. First Chose 2 from that 8 and then 1 from 6 and then arrange them all in line, so you have $${8\choose 2} \cdot {6\choose 1} \cdot {13!\over 3!3!2!}=13!{7\over 3}$$
- Exactly 1 is. Then exactly three are twice and four once. First Chose 1 from that 8 and then 3 from 7 and then arrange them all in line, so you have $${8\choose 1} \cdot {7\choose 3} \cdot {13!\over 3!2!^3}=13!{35\over 6}$$
- No one is 3 times . Then exactly five are twice and three once. First Chose 5 from that 8 and then arrange them all in line, so you have $${8\choose 5} \cdot {13!\over 2!^5}=13!{7\over 4}$$

Sum all that and we get $11!\cdot 91\cdot 17$

Answer (score 0):

You can tell that there are 3 categories here to make $A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H=13$:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H       SUM
2   2   2   2   2   1   1   1       13
3   3   2   1   1   1   1   1       13
3   2   2   2   1   1   1   1       13
```

If you look at the first row you can arrange it with: $\frac{8!}{(3!*5!)} = 56$ ways.

Sum all categories together you get: $56+168+280=504$

Comment: there is no 8! rearrangements, if we talk about the same person then interviewing him first then third is the same as interviewing him third then first...

Comment: still the answer is wrong

Comment: @clark_smith if you know the answer - share it or point what is wrong.

Comment: @clark_smith btw, you wrote: “the total number of interviews is 13 and that order matters” doesn’t that strongly imply the order for each interviewer matters? Example: If A comes first then third shouldn’t that matter?